# what is the regexp to accept

Tags: regex, json, jsonschema

I have a last name in json request and i need to build schema for the json.

I have the schema as

```
        "lastName": {
            "type": "string", 
            "required": true,
            "pattern":"^[a-zA-Z0-9'. ]{1,40}$"
        }
```

But we got defect saying lastnames can be as follows.

Last names: apostrophe, hyphen, period (O’Rourke; Smith-Jones; St. Pierre).

Fixed the apostrophe, period and space but don't know how to put  hyphen.
Please let me know how to fix this.

Comment: What is the point of applying such validation to a name?  I would also argue why separate first name and last name.  Give this little article a read: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape it with a backslash (it can then be placed anywhere in the regex):

```
^[\-a-zA-Z0-9'. ]
```

or place it at the end (where it cannot be mistakenly parsed as a range separator):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9'. -]
```

Answer (score 1):

The hyphen can be put at the end of the list, which makes it clear that it's not a character range:

```
[.....-]
```

Note: I wouldn't accept special characters at the beginning of the name.